# Extract part of a string in BASH

Tags: bash, sed

I have a puzzle to solve which I could not do on my own. I believe it may be a simple one for others. I was trying to solve in a one liner.

I have following strings:

```
Tree-Forest
Vegetable-fruit-Garden
Fish-Frog-Ponds
Chicken-Duck-Farm
```

I need to extract the part before last -, like (omitting the last - and the string after that):

```
Tree
Vegetable-fruit
Fish-Frog
Chicken-Duck
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you read the bash documentation on [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)? It shows all the operations you can perform, including this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH string manipulations:

```
s='Tree-Forest Vegetable-fruit-Garden Fish-Frog-Ponds Chicken-Duck-Farm'
echo "${s%-*}"
Tree-Forest Vegetable-fruit-Garden Fish-Frog-Ponds Chicken-Duck
```

After edited question it seems you're editing a file then you can use `sed` also:

```
sed 's/-[^-]*$//' file
Tree
Vegetable-fruit
Fish-Frog
Chicken-Duck
```

Comment: Where does the question mention a file?

Comment: Before editing I thought it is all in one single string but now it says `I have following strings`. Now difficult to see how strings are available in a block like this unless there is file. If not a file then `sed 's/-[^-]*$//' <<< "$input"`

Comment: Maybe in a `for` or `while` loop that sets the variable to each string.

Comment: OP says **I was trying to solve in a one liner** and doesn't provide details then.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for solving this. Please explain what [^-]*$ means?

Comment: I forgot to clarify my question. All the strings are provided in a text file.Comes one per line.

Comment: In that case sed is the right solution for you. `-[^-]*$` is a regex which means match hyphen followed by 0 or more of any character that is not hyphen till end of input.